# Why can't I store a value in transform.position.y?

Tags: c#, unity

Well I have this line of code

```
            Vector3 pos = cell.CellPosition;
            float light1Height = 10f;
            pos.y = light1Height;

            lightGameObject.transform.position.y = light1Height;
            lightGameObject.transform.position.x = pos.x;
            lightGameObject.transform.position.z = pos.z;
```

The error states that

Cannot modify a value type return of 'UnityEngine.Transform.position". Consider storing the value in a temporary variable.

What should i do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the property transform.position returns you **a copy** of the Vector3 position. Modifying the copy won't modify the original struct. You should therefore create a new Vector3 and replace the current position with it.

```
lightGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x, light1Height, pos.z);
```

You can also store the value in a temporary variable.

```
Vector3 position = lightGameObject.transform.position;
position.y = light1Height;
position.x = pos.x;
position.z = pos.z;
lightGameObject.transform.position = position;
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# when a struct is accessed via a getter (like transform.position), the compiler won't allow you to modify a member, because it has no sense to do that, because a getter of a struct return a brand new struct that you have to reference first. If you don't your brand new struct will stay inaccessible...